# publish asp.net mvc 4 site gave 404 on IIS 6 host

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, http-status-code-404, publish

Newly created ASP.Net MVC 4, C# project with VS Express 2012 for Web, target .Net Framework version 4.0 (same as the remote host).
Debugging directly through VS is find. After publishing to local folder, [**original:**<strike>There is no .aspx generated, only **sitename.dll**, there were even original **.cshtml** files</strike>] and copying to IIS Express `C:\inetpub\www` folder, `http://localhost/Home` is fine.

But when I upload everything to host (according to **info.aspx**, server info: IIS 6.0, .Net Version 4.0.30319.239), `http://domain/Home` gave `page cannot be found` 404 error, which seems like a routing problem.

Here is my **Web.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-FireupCooking.Net4._0-20130620031747;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-FireupCooking.Net4._0-20130620031747.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Here are the files under **bin/**:

```
Antlr3.Runtime.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.dll
EntityFramework.dll
FireupCooking.Net4.0.dll
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll
Newtonsoft.Json.dll
System.Net.Http.dll
System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll
System.Web.Helpers.dll
System.Web.Http.dll
System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll
System.Web.Mvc.dll
System.Web.Optimization.dll
System.Web.Razor.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
System.Web.WebPages.dll
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
WebGrease.dll
WebMatrix.Data.dll
WebMatrix.WebData.dll
```

I also tried the following minimal `web.config`, info.aspx <strike>still gave the **Server Application Unavailable** error</strike>. **UPDATE:** This file now showing server info.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Static files html, gif and simple *.aspx*s are fine. Only MVC pathes `/Home/Index` and `/Home` gave **404 - not found** error.

What should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

What you got on the local side is correct. .Csthml files are the web pages when using Razor.

Did you set up IIS correctly on the Host? You have to create a website and make sure that the Application pool is using the correct .Net Version.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. I found a `info.apx` online which is said to be similar to `phpinfo`, and realized the target host .Net Framework is 2.0. Now I had the provider set it for 4.0, but `info.apx` is giving me **Server Application Unavailable**. I saw the log (seems like only an access log), and found out status code 500 0 0, no additional info.

Comment: And I published to project to local file system, and copied to local IIS Express folder, and visited the http://localhost and http://localhost/Host both successfully. Then I uploaded everything to remote host, visited the visited http://~domain~/Home, but that gave me 404

Comment: Can you send me what you are recieving exactly now when you try to access the page? Also did you set up a virtual directory or an individual website for the application? Try also placing a single simple html file inside the location to ensure that it is an issue with IIS config and not with your application

Comment: Thanks for the response. I only have FTP access to the host, so can't do server side config. I got a 2nd host with similar system, and tried to put the same files there. Then learned that I had to register router in `global.asax.cs` to make MVC 4 work with IIS 6, after that it is working on the 2nd host. On the desired host, `.html`, `.gif` static files are fine, but I just get "Server Application Unavailable" even when I access the simple one line file right now. So I guess it is the server config problem, but not sure what.

Comment: I am almost sure its related to the server configuration. See if someone can check it out for you.

Comment: Thanks. Since I am new to ASP.Net world, I kept feeling I'm missing something else. Now I am contacting the host providers to configure the server properly for MVC.

Answer (score 0):

[Using ASP.NET MVC with Different Versions of IIS (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs) had it step by step for shared host IIS 6 to use MVC routing. It was even on the VS generated page, but I had ignored it.

So for anyone else having the similar headache, here is important parts.
1. Assuming it is a **shared host** that we can't do much server config.
2. **IIS 6, .Net 4.0**, and possibly Windows 2003

In our Asp.Net MVC 4, `global.asax.cs` register routs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = "" }
      );

    routes.MapRoute(
      "Root",
      "",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "root" }
    );
}
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);  //RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes didn't work
}
```

Since `.aspx` files are directed to ASP.Net for processing, these routing rules will catch `http://domain/home.apspx/index` to invoke `HomeController.Index`.
If there is a need to ignore some files, just prepend a ignoring rule like below

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("info.aspx");

routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```